# WPF - Programmatically created controls validation in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, combobox

I'm struggling with weird issue in my WPF code. I have a combobox, which allows user to choose one of its options. Each item in this combobox is some kind of `string.Format()` pattern. For example when user chooses option `'Hello {0} world'`, my code generates two `TextBlocks` with `'Hello'` and `'world'` and one `TextBox` between them, where user can provide his input.

Here's my xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PossiblePatternOptions}" DisplayMemberPath="Pattern" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPattern, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="250" Margin="5,0,25,0"/>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedPattern.GeneratedControls}"/>
```

`SelectedPattern.GeneratedControls` is an `ObservableCollection<UIElement>`:

```
public ObservableCollection<UIElement> GeneratedControls
{
   get
   {
      return _generatedControls ?? (_generateControls = new ObservableCollection<UIElement>(GenerateControls(_splittedPattern)));
   }
}
```

Here's how I create new `TextBox` (in `GenerateControls` method):

```
var placeholderChunk = chunk as TextBoxPlaceholder;
var textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.ToolTip = placeholderChunk.Description;

Binding binding = new Binding("Value");
binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;

binding.Source = placeholderChunk;
binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

`TextBoxPlaceholder` implements `IDataErrorInfo` and provides error details for incorrect input:

```
public class TextBoxPlaceholder : IDataErrorInfo
{
   public string Value {get;set;}

   public string this[string columnName]
   {
      get
      {
         switch (columnName)
         {
            case "Value":
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Value) ? "Error" : string.Empty;

            default:
            return string.Empty;
         }
      }
    }

   public string Error
   {
      get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
   }
}
```

The problem is that when I choose an option from combobox for the first time, generated `TextBoxes` are validated correctly and they get nice red frame around them, but when I choose an option that has been chosen previously, no validation occurs and there is no red frame anymore. I noticed that when I change code in `GeneratedControls` property so it recreates collection every time, it works ok. What could possibly be the problem here?

I know it may be explained poorly, in case of any misunderstandings I will clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your "Value" property does not fire an update when it changes, so the text binding of the text box cannot react on the change and will not evaluate the value again. Try something like this:

```
// implmeent INotifyPropertyChanged
public class TextBoxPlaceholder : IDataErrorInfo, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string mValue;

    public string Value 
    {
        get{ return mValue; }
        // fire notification
        set{mValue = value;NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");}
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // helper method
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    // your code goes here
```

Comment: It didn't help and I think the notification mechanism is used only when you update your property from code. I noticed one weird thing though. When I enter valid input to my textbox and delete it (i.e make it invalid again), red frame appears. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your binding and error handling looks fine to me, the only thing which came in mind:
Are you sure that your **"Value"** property is cleared when you choose a new entry from your combo box? 
It seems that your "Value" is only cleared at the beginning and when you clear it manually (and then your error validation works) but not when you choose a new entry.

Comment: When I choose a new entry, the control is created and it works. When I choose it for the second time, validation breaks. It starts working again after typing correct input and invalidating it again. In every case PropertyChanged event is fired and Value property is set correctly. I suspect that it might be the problem with ItemsControl itself. For now I create control every time combobox entry is chosen and don't chache them. When I have more time I will investigate it further.

Comment: That sounds like a good workaround, let me know if you found the issue, I am curious what could have been the problem.